# Screensaver is only activated the first time Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I have set a screensaver on my windows 7 machine and set it to 1 min. It works only one time then after that if I wait more than 1 min it is not activated, I then restarted the machine then it works the first time then nothing after that and so on. I checked online and some people suggested that it might be the mouse but I used another mouse and same thing and I even unplugged the mouse and the screensaver wasn't activated. I read here https://superuser.com/a/54763/391215 that Windows 7 automatically increases the delay if the screensaver is interrupted shortly after activating which is exactly my case as I am using screensaver to run a program, but I cannot find where is this option in windows 7. Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix please?

EDIT:

As per the answer suggested, I've checked the Adaptive display idle timeout in regedit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\90959d22-d6a1-49b9-af93-bce885ad335b` and it is disabled as shown in the below screenshot. I restarted the machine and it still worked only the first time but not after that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called
[Adaptive display idle timeout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/display-settings-adaptive-display-idle-timeout),
defined as:

> Specifies whether the OS automatically scales the display idle time-out based on user activity.
>
> If the user provides input to the system shortly after the display idle timeout is reached, Windows automatically extends the display idle time-out to deliver a better user experience.

To disable the feature, create and execute the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\90959d22-d6a1-49b9-af93-bce885ad335b]
"Attributes"=dword:00000001
```

You may also disable "Adaptive display" in Power Options:

[image]

For more information see
[How to Add or Remove "Adaptive display" from Power Options in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108142-add-remove-adaptive-display-power-options-windows.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I couldn't find the Adaptive display in the Power options so I checked the Regedit and found it is already disabled. I've updated my question with a screenshot. I'd appreciate your help as I am stuck and I am really trying to fix it.

Comment: I don't think you need the timeout to test your screensaver. If you can see it when right-clicking on the desktop, Personalization, Screen saver settings, the Preview button should run it.

Comment: Thanks. So what do you mean by "you need the timeout to test your screensaver"?My target is to set it to run once the computer is idle for 5 mins but it only run the first time of 5 min inactivity then when the screensaver is terminated by a user activity and then the next time it's inactive for 5 mins it doesn't run again. Any idea why or how to get it working every time the computer is inactive for x amount of time?

Comment: Misunderstanding. For the missing options, see [How to Add or Remove "Adaptive display" from Power Options in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108142-add-remove-adaptive-display-power-options-windows.html). If this doesn't help, then I really don't know why these well-known fixes don't work for you.

Comment: So for me the Adaptive display option should be displayed(visible) or not? and should be on or off? And according to my screenshot of the regedit in my question is it the correct settings or do I need to do something? If you could advise me as my goal is to make my screenshot runs every time not just the first time. Many thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: You want it to be visible in Power Options, to use in the second part of my answer. This is only in the hope that it does something else in addition to this registry setting. As another try, you could set the registry `Attributes` to `0` and reboot, and maybe it will change something.